# Entity Framework buggy when invoking stored procedure via Database.SqlQuery

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When invoking a stored procedure with a parameter of type int and value 0, Entity Framework sends a null value to the server.

```
var requiredIntParameter = new SqlParameter("RequiredInt", 0);
var tableParameter = new SqlParameter("@Table", System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured);
... table creation ....
List<ReturnType> result = DBContext.Database.SqlQuery<ReturnType>("EXEC NAMEOFSPROC "
           + "@RequiredInt, "
           + "@Table, "
           requiredIntParameter ,
           tableParameter,
           );
```

Entity Framework log:

```
Opened connection at 1/10/2018 4:42:09 PM +01:00
EXEC NAMEOFSPROC @RequiredInt, @Table
-- RequiredInt: 'null' (Type = Int64, IsNullable = false)
-- @Table: '' (Type = Object, IsNullable = false)
-- Executing at 1/10/2018 4:42:09 PM +01:00
-- Completed in 40 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

Resulting exception:

> The parameterized query '(@RequiredInt int' expects the parameter   @RequiredInt'), which was not supplied.

Note: As Sproc has a table parameter,

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction
```

is not an option for me!

Using:

- EF 6.2.0
- SQL Server 2008

Comment: Looks like missing @ before RequiredInt parameter.

Comment: That error does not mean that a null value was passed, it means that the calling batch omitted the parameter entirely. Please include a complete repro. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i think the log is very clear about what has been sent to the server

Comment: this parameter gets ommited: 
    var requiredIntParameter = new SqlParameter("RequiredInt", typeof(int));

Comment: this parameter results in null in sprocc invocation: 
    var requiredIntParameter = new SqlParameter("RequiredInt", 0);

Answer (score 1):

There is a Workaround:

```
var requiredIntParameter = new SqlParameter("RequiredInt", typeof(int)); 
requiredIntParameter.Value = 0;
```

Now log is

```
EXECSPROC @RequiredInt, @Table
-- RequiredInt: '0' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
-- @Table: '' (Type = Object, IsNullable = false)
-- Executing at 1/10/2018 4:42:09 PM +01:00
```

-- Completed in 40 ms with result: SqlDataReader

And everything is fine!